# Sorting data in HTML table

Tags: php, html, sorting, html-table

Hope you can help,

I have a database that I am querying from into a php file and doing some further processing on.

I need a way of sorting the results in a table by $distance (lowest first) - but as this is not part of the database I can't build ORDER BY into the query.

$distance is calculated by a php function and represents the distance between two UK locations

/* <----  code to calculate the distance between 2 points here --------> */

```
 echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location One</th>
    <th>Distance</th>       
    <th>Require Delivery To</th>
    <th>Location Two</th>
    </tr>";

if($distance < 5) // if less than 5 miles
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['locationOne'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" ."approx ". $distance. " miles" ."</td>";               
    echo "<td>" . $row['locationTwo']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
 }
```

/* <--need a way of presenting these results sorted by lowest distance first in the table    headers above  --> */

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to do the sorting before even echoing the table. PHP has quite a few methods for sorting an array based on the value of the elements. Here is the official documentation on the functions [php.net/array.sorting](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). Easiest will be something like this:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
  return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
}
```

`usort($myArray, 'sortByOrder');`

Answer (score 0):

Just loop again after calculating the distance.

```
   $rows_within_distance = array();
   foreach ($rows as &$row) {
        // calc $distance
        $row['distance'] = $distance;
        if ($distance < 5) $rows_within_distance = $row;
   }
   usort($rows_within_distance, function($a, $b) {
       return $a['distance'] - $b['distance'];
   });
   foreach ($rows_within_distance as $row) {
       // output; echo <tr>....</tr>
   }
```

Comment: Hi,  what is &$row ? is it a typo or somethng I dont know about yet !!

Comment: The variable is assigned by reference, so if you modify `$row` in the loop `$rows[i]` will actually be modified. Read more about it in de foreach docs: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

```
// Your db result assumed
$db_results = array(
              array(
                  'name' => 'name1',
                  'locationOne' => 'loc1a',
                  'locationTwo' => 'loc1b',
               ),
              array(
                  'name' => 'name2',
                  'locationOne' => 'loc2a',
                  'locationTwo' => 'loc2b',
               ),
              array(
                  'name' => 'name3',
                  'locationOne' => 'loc3a',
                  'locationTwo' => 'loc3b',
               ),
           );

// Calculated the distance and stored in another array
$result = array(); 
$i = 0;
foreach($db_results as $res)
{
    $result[$i] = $res;

    // calculating distance and adding to the array
    $result[$i]['distance'] = your_function($res['locationOne'], $res['locationTwo']);
    $i++;
}

// Function for Multi-dimensional Sort Array by Value
function array_sort_by_column(&$arr, $col, $dir = SORT_ASC) 
{
    $sort_col = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key=> $row) 
    {
        $sort_col[$key] = $row[$col];
    }

    array_multisort($sort_col, $dir, $arr);
}


// Sorted the array
array_sort_by_column($result, 'distance');

// Printed the final table
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Location One</th>
    <th>Distance</th>       
    <th>Require Delivery To</th>
    <th>Location Two</th>
    </tr>";

foreach($result as $res)
{
    if($res['distance'] < 5)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $res['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $res['locationOne'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" ."approx ". $res['distance']. " miles" ."</td>";               
        echo "<td>" . $res['locationTwo']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

echo "</table>";
```